# Python most efficient way to keep sorted data

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

What is the most efficient way to keep track of data in a ascending/descending order.  Lets say I have a stream of data, assume this is very large.  Sample stream:

```
key,mod,value
5,add,1
2,add,3
4,add,2
2,add,2
2,rem,5
```

As I am reading the stream, I place it in a dictionary to keep track of the contents. For example, at the end of the mini stream above, I will have a dictionary with `{5:1, 4:2}`.  Where `add` means the value is increased by the value, and `rem` means you are removing that much from that key.  If the value goes to 0, then delete that key from the dictionary.  But I also want to be able to print the data in order (but doesnt have to be all the time.)  I do want to keep track of the highest/lowest keys, so that I know when the highest/lowest value has changed.  Either the key changed or its value changed.

The way I am doing it right now is fill/delete keys from dictionary accordingly.  This should be constant O(1).  Keep track of a `sorted_keys` list, where each stream checks if the new number is in the dictionary, if not, will do `bisect.insort_right(sorted_keys, key)`.  So the `sorted_keys` is always sorted at all times.  Assuming adding 1 value in a sorted list is quick, though it does need to extend the size so this may take O(n) still.  And i keep track of `prev_highest` or `prev_lowest`, and check this against sorted_keys[0] or sorted_keys[-1] respectively.

I tried using deque with bisect.insort_right, SortedDict from sortedcontainers, linked list, OrderedDict, but it seems that the above seems to work best.  Is there another potential implementation that could be more optimized?  Or should I just keep track of a certain level in order, say 10 items in order.  And update that accordingly.  But the problem with this is that if there is a new key, how do i know its one of the new top or not?  Seems like having a heapq would help, but I cant get the sorted values until i pop them.  And if I need to print the whole thing in order, I just sort the keys of the entire dictionary.

Edit:
Adding my tests using bisect and SortedDict below:

```
import timeit
import bisect
import random
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

NUM_ITERATION_TEST = 10
TOTAL_NUM_DATA = 1000000
MODS = ['add', 'rem']
QUANTITY = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000]

DATA = [{'mod': random.choice(MODS),
         'key': random.randint(0, 1000),
         'val': random.choice(QUANTITY)} for x in range(TOTAL_NUM_DATA)]


def method1(DATA):
    d = {}
    sorted_keys = []

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                bisect.insort_right(sorted_keys, key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    sorted_keys.remove(key)           
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass # Deleting something not there yet

def method2(DATA):
    d = SortedDict()

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass  # Deleting something not there yet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # METHOD 1
    print("Method 1 Execution Time:")
    print(timeit.timeit("test_timeit.method1(test_timeit.DATA)",
                        number=NUM_ITERATION_TEST,
                        setup="import test_timeit"))

    # METHOD 2
    print("Method 2 Execution Time:")
    print(timeit.timeit("test_timeit.method2(test_timeit.DATA)",
                        number=NUM_ITERATION_TEST,
                        setup="import test_timeit"))
```

The results for the above is:

```
Method 1 Execution Time:
4.427699800000001
Method 2 Execution Time:
12.7445671
```

Comment: It is hard to give a general answer to the sorting problem. Sorting is one of larger problems in computer science and many algorithms have been created. Just to name one concept to store data in an ordered fashion: b-trees.

Comment: Sorry, but the sample input appears to be gibberish - what does "add" mean" What does "rem" mean? ;How on Earth do you get `{5:1, 4:2}` out of those 6 lines? Is the "key,mod,value" line part of the input, or is it meant to be commentary of some kind?  I've read this 4 times now, and have no real idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the dict is large (I know that this is vague) an sqlite database with an index may also be an option (maybe hold in memory). The indexes are B-trees and automatically kept up to date by the database.

Comment: @TimPeters I updated the question.  Add means add that value to that key, and rem means remove that value from that key.  The headers is more to just describe each columns

Comment: The tasks of keeping track of items of various quantities and reporting on the most and least common ones are well-suited to `collections.Counter`. What are your performance requirements, and what is the performance of your current approach?

Comment: Regardless of dict flavor, never test for membership with `k in thedict.keys()`. That requires building a keys object every time, which is pure wasted time and space. Do `k in thedict` instead, which _directly_ calls the primitive `thedict.__contains__(k)` method.

Comment: And note that you only have 1001 possible keys in your test driver. That's **tiny**.  That's the primary reason SortedDict isn't helping - it's a near-trivially small data structure.  OK, you may/add subtract things in QUANTITY to/from those keys too, but it's still a small number of possibilities.

Comment: Yea running it on bigger number but taking some time.  Will try bigger numbers.  Also, will do k in thedict instead of thedict.keys() like you mentioned

Comment: In a quick stab, changing `randint(0, 1000)` to upper bound 10000 (10x larger, but still "small") made the bisect method about 10x slower but only boosted the SortedDict spelling by 2 seconds - and also changing member testing to plain `k in thedict` (no `.keys()` calls). If your real data really does have a small number of possible integer keys, forget **all** of this and just use a list _indexed_ by key (use., e.g., `None` to mean "not here").

Comment: And with upper bound 40000, bisect took over 4 minutes to complete but SortedDict under 11 seconds.While this is still "on the small-ish side", the quadratic-time nature of repeating Python's `list.insert()` (explained in my answer) is quickly becoming overwhelmingly dominating.

Comment: And see my new edit for another seemingly worthwhile speed boost.

Comment: @TimPeters Thanks a lot for looking further into this.  Yea I didnt even try SortedList, but def seems better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For data that fits in memory, "SortedDict from sortedcontainers" (which you already tried) is generally as good as it gets for keeping such a dict in sorted order.  But lookup time is (roughly) `O(log N)` (see edit at the end - that appears to be false!).

> Assuming adding 1 value in a sorted list is quick, though it does need to extend the size so this may take O(n) still.

In a Python list `L`, inserting an element at index `i` has to - at a minimum - physically move `len(L) - i` pointers, which means 8x times that many bytes on a 64-bit box.  That's where sortedcontainers gets its huge wins when data gets "large": the worst-case number of pointers it needs to physically move is bounded by a constant independent of `len(L)`.  Until `len(L)` gets into the thousands, it can be hard to notice the difference. But when `len(L)` gets into the millions, the difference is huge.

I'd try a compromise:  use a sortedcontainers SortedList to keep track of the current keys, and a plain Python dict for the actual dict.  Then:

For "key add value": see if the key is in the dict. Very fast. If it is, no need to touch the SortedList. Just mutate the dict. If the key is not in the dict, then it needs to be added to the SortedList and the dict.

For "key rem value": see if the key in the dict. If it's not, I have no idea what you want to do, but you'll figure it out ;-) But if it is in the dict, subtract the value. If the result is non-zero you're done. Else (result is 0), remove the key from the dict and the SortedList.

Note: I'm suggesting SortedList instead of SortedSet not for semantic reasons, but because SortedSet requires more memory, to maintain a set in parallel with a sorted list. You have no use for the set.

What you may *really* want in addition to a dict is a [double-ended ("min max") heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap).  It's impossible to guess from what you've said - it depends on, e.g., how often you only want to know "the smallest and/or the largest" compared to often you want to materialize the entire sorted order.  But I don't know of a min-max heap implementation for Python that's built for speed - they're messy beasts to code, and rarely used.

### EDIT

On second thought, it seems that a sortedcontainer's SortedDict already combines a SortedList with (a subclass of) a plain Python dict.  For example, setting a value in a SortedDict is implemented like so:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key not in self:
        self._list_add(key)
    dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

So it only touches the SortedList if the key isn't already in the dict.  There's not *much* opportunity for improving on this if you maintain your own <SortedList, dict> pair.

### ROLLING YOUR OWN

Here's another to try:

```
def method3(DATA):
    sorted_keys = SortedList()
    d = {}

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d:
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                sorted_keys.add(key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d:
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    sorted_keys.remove(key)
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass  # Deleting something not there yet
```

This implements my original suggestion: maintain your own pair of a SortedList with a plain Python dict.  It has the same `O()` behavior as using a SortedDict, but appears significantly faster by a constant factor.  The seems partly because the dict operations are all coded in C now (SortedDict is coded in Python), and the rest because we only test for dict membership once per `data` item.  For example, in

```
if key in d:
    d[key] += data['val']
```

when `d` is a SortedDict, `key in d` tests it once explicitly, but the implementation of `d.__setitem__()` has to test it again, so that it can add `key` to its hidden SortedList if the key is unknown.  From our higher-level view, we already know the key is in the dict in the body of the `if`, so can ignore our explicit SortedList entirely there.

Comment: Yea i used SortedDict, thinking it'll be better.  Unfortunately, it is not.  Let me update my question with my profile testing.  Unless I messed up something there

Comment: The closest you got quantifying your problem size is "very large" - but nobody knows what that means to you ;-)

Comment: True, I guess thats vague.  But seems no matter what value I put in the test above, the bisect implementation will still win.  Please let me know if you see something different

Comment: Woohoo, I've [beaten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63767577/13008439) *that* Tim Peters in something sorting! I can retire now :-)

Comment: @superb rain, heh - read the comments on the original post all the way through. The original problem instance is nearly trivial, because its `random.randint(0, 1000)` means there are at most 1001 keys in the dict. Nothing beats a plain list for something so tiny.  But changing 1000 to something even as small as 40000 makes it **crawl** compared to what I posted.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to read them initially. I'll rerun with 40000 (only our two solutions). I don't think mine will **crawl**, as I fixed their main mistake of using `sorted_keys.remove(key)`.

Comment: Done, see the added times in my answer. Not much slower than yours.

Comment: Sure, the `.remove()` in the original was begging for trouble. But as my answer already explained, as the number of keys becomes ever larger, using a plain Python list is doomed to become enormously slower, due to the inherently quadratic-time nature of repeating inserts and deletes "in the middle" of a flat list. This is precisely the problem `SortedList` addresses, cleverly exploiting that flat lists are - to the contrary - quite fast when they're short.  40000 is still on the "tiny" _side_.

Answer (score 3):

You made two mistakes in your `method1`:

- You check `if key in d.keys():` instead of `if key in d:`. There's no point creating a keys view there.
- You remove from the list with `sorted_keys.remove(key)` instead of using `bisect` to find the index and then deleting that index.

Fixing those, storing some methods in local variables for shorter/faster access, and using `d.get` to possibly find a key and get its value (instead of an `in` check followed by looking up the value), I get these times (method1/2 are yours, method3 is Tim's, method4 is mine):

```
Round 1
method1 7.590627200000004
method2 19.851634099999984
method3 6.093115100000006
method4 5.069753999999989

Round 2
method1 7.857367500000009
method2 19.59779759999998
method3 6.057990299999972
method4 5.0046839999999975

Round 3
method1 7.843560700000012
method2 19.8673627
method3 6.079332300000033
method4 5.073929300000032
```

Tim challenged me to change `randint(0, 1000)` to `randint(0, 40_000)`:

```
method1 607.2835661000001
method2 26.667593300000135
method3 12.84969140000021
method4 16.68231250000008
```

And `randint(0, 400_000)` (only the faster solutions):

```
method3 20.179627500000002
method4 115.39424580000002
```

My version:

```
def method4(DATA):
    d = {}
    sorted_keys = []
    insort = bisect.insort_right
    index = bisect.bisect_left
    get = d.get
    
    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            val = get(key)
            if val:
                d[key] = val + data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                insort(sorted_keys, key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            val = get(key)
            if val:
                if val <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    del sorted_keys[index(sorted_keys, key)]
                else:
                    d[key] = val - data['val']
            else:
                pass # Deleting something not there yet
```

Full benchmark code including correctness checking:

```
import timeit
import bisect
import random
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict, SortedList

NUM_ITERATION_TEST = 10
TOTAL_NUM_DATA = 1000000
MODS = ['add', 'rem']
QUANTITY = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000]

DATA = [{'mod': random.choice(MODS),
         'key': random.randint(0, 1000),
         'val': random.choice(QUANTITY)} for x in range(TOTAL_NUM_DATA)]

def method1(DATA, return_=False):
    d = {}
    sorted_keys = []

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                bisect.insort_right(sorted_keys, key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    sorted_keys.remove(key)           
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass # Deleting something not there yet
    if return_:
        return d, sorted_keys

def method2(DATA, return_=False):
    d = SortedDict()

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d.keys():
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass  # Deleting something not there yet
    if return_:
        return dict(d), list(d)

def method3(DATA, return_=False):
    sorted_keys = SortedList()
    d = {}

    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d:
                d[key] += data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                sorted_keys.add(key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            if key in d:
                if d[key] <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    sorted_keys.remove(key)
                else:
                    d[key] -= data['val']
            else:
                pass  # Deleting something not there yet
    if return_:
        return d, list(sorted_keys)

def method4(DATA, return_=False):
    d = {}
    sorted_keys = []
    insort = bisect.insort_right
    index = bisect.bisect_left
    get = d.get
    
    for data in DATA:
        if data['mod'] == 'add':
            key = data['key']
            val = get(key)
            if val:
                d[key] = val + data['val']
            else:
                d[key] = data['val']
                insort(sorted_keys, key)
        elif data['mod'] == 'rem':
            key = data['key']
            val = get(key)
            if val:
                if val <= data['val']:
                    del d[key]
                    del sorted_keys[index(sorted_keys, key)]
                else:
                    d[key] = val - data['val']
            else:
                pass # Deleting something not there yet
    if return_:
        return d, sorted_keys

methods = method1, method2, method3, method4

expect = method1(DATA, True)
for method in methods[1:]:
    print(method(DATA, True) == expect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for round in range(1, 4):
        print('Round', round)
        for method in methods:
            t = min(timeit.repeat(lambda: method(DATA),
                                  number=NUM_ITERATION_TEST))
            print(method.__name__, t)
        print()
```

Comment: Now try 400000 ;-) The difference starts to get dramatic then.   The quadratic-time behavior in the original was dominated by `.remove()`, but it's still there in `method4` due to the `insort()` and `del d[key]` lines - but those run "at C speed" so it takes larger lists for those lines to utterly overwhelm everything else the program is doing.

Comment: Nah, why would I do that? I already know just as much as you do that it'll get that much slower for that reason.

Comment: Sorry, but nothing in your answer, or your comments, suggested you had any idea why I suggested `SortedList` to begin with. To the contrary, your answer suggested continuing to use a plain list, with changes that didn't alter `O()` behavior at all. But I up-voted your answer anyway ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Right, sorry. I guess I consider it common knowledge, and my comment was supposed to be lighthearted but ended up being flippant. I do know more than I've shown, might even know something about Timsort that you don't :-). When I said I've beaten you at something sorting, I just meant the OP's benchmark as is. I did 400,000 after all now, as I wasn't able to estimate the effect on the interplay with the other parameters and the whole benchmark. I mean, it also matters how often we insert or remove. I'd say now my answer is clear that mine is significantly slower at large key sets.

Comment: @superbrain Definitely will keep your answer in mind.  Definitely a great alternative (if <40k).  Good idea using index when removing for sure